# List<? extends Base> VS List<Base>

Tags: java, generics

```
List<? extends Base> list

List<Base> list
```

Is there any difference between the two declarations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

`List<Base>` can contain a mixture of different things that all derive from `Base`.  `List<? extend Base>` contains homogeneous items (in the sense that they must all derive from some specific, unknown type that in turn derives from `Base`).

Put another way, `List<? extends Base>` is the base class for `List<T extends Base>`.  So you can pass a `List<T extends Base>` to any method that takes a `List<? extends Base>`.  The same is not true for methods that take a `List<Base>`.

Comment: In particular, you can't add an object of type `Base` to a `List<? extends Base>`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Not only that, but you can't add *any* object (except `null`) to a `List<? extends Base>`, because you don't know what type the `?` represents.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: So in short, List<? extends Base> can be passed to any method that takes either List<? extends Base>, List<Base>, List<Child>, or List<GrandChild> ? Then why would anyone want to use List<Base> ? What also puzzles me is that you can do .add(...) on both List<? extends Base> and List<Base>, where the '...' can be anything that is either Base or derived (directly or indirectly) from Base.

Comment: You've got it exactly backwards.   List<? extends Base>, List<Base>, List<Child>, or List<GrandChild> can be passed to a method that takes a List<? extends Base>, but not the other way around.  You can't add _anything_ to a List<? extends Base>, but you can add anything that extends Base to a List<Base>.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I guess it'd just take sometime to get this kind of things all clear!

Answer (score 9):

`List<Base> list` can contain elements of type `Base` or any of its subtypes. Some example with the JDK classes:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects.add(new Object()); // adding an Object instance
objects.add("I am a String"); // a String instance is also an Object
objects.add(Integer.valueOf(5)); // an Integer instance is also an Object
```

But when you retrieve the elements, you can assign them only to variables of the `Object` class, because `Object` is the type parameter of the declared list.

```
Object first = objects.get(1);
Object second = objects.get(2);
Object third = objects.get(3);
```

Their real runtime classes are still `Object`, `String` and `Integer`, so you can cast them to those types and work with them as such, but such casts may fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` if not done right and it's generally not a good idea to work with lists in such fashion.

`List<? extends Base> list` is a declaration that is not actually designated for declaring variables, because as already mentioned in Daniel Pryden's comment - you cannot `add()` any object in it, only `null`s.

```
List<? extends String> list = new ArrayList<? extends String>();
list.add("a String")); // compile error!
```

But you can use such a *bounded wildcard* expression for generic method parameters. An example from the `List` itself is the `addAll()` method whose signature is this:

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
```

This enables you to do something like this:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects.addAll(strings);
```

Without the `<? extend E>` wildcard it wouldn't be possible to add those `String`s into the `List` of `Object`s, because generic types (unlike arrays) are not *covariant*. That means that a `List<String>` **is not** a subtype of `List<Object>`. But any `String` is an `Object`, right? So therefore it is necessary to declare the method parameter with the bounded wildcard - a `List<String>` **is** a subtype of `List<? extends Object>`.

Again, I have to point out - the bounded wildcard are primarily designated for **generic method parameters**, not for method return types or variable declarations.